# javascript: dynamically remove divs

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm very new to javascript.  The page I am creating has a bunch of forms on it that will hold different data.  I've managed to put together the following script that allows me to add more divs by ID.

What I would now like to do is be able to add a button to each of the new divs that allows that specific div to be removed.

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 30;
function addInput(what) {
        if (counter == limit)  {
                alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
        }
        else {
        var container = document.getElementById(what);
        var clone = container.cloneNode(true);
                clone.setAttribute('id','div_'+document.getElementById(what).getElementsByTagName('div').length);
        container.appendChild (clone);
        counter++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var remButton=document.createElement('button');
remButton.textContent='Remove';//or something else
remButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)
},false);
clone.appendChild(remButton);
```

Put that just before `container.appendChild(clone);`

Comment: Thank you.  Definitely adds the button.  The challenge is that if you add forms to a couple of different sections the remove button removes everything added rather than just the last one.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but this should only remove the `clone` element

Comment: If there is a form to add more cookies and another for bananas,  you can now add more of each form.  If I add one of each form then decide to remove one this script ends up removing all of the new forms I've added dynamically.